# Detect and remove duplicates on Dropbox online without local download

Tags: dropbox, online-storage, online-backup

I back up all my files on Dropbox. Over the years, I am sure that I have many duplicate files and I would like to detect and remove them. I know that there are many software solutions to detect and remove duplicates, but the challenge is that I use the online sync-only feature of Dropbox, so most of my Dropbox files are only available online, not on my local computer. For example, I have around 1.5 TB of files in my online Dropbox but my local computer can store less than 500 GB. If I were to compare files with the typical duplicate finder, they would download all my Dropbox files locally to do the comparison. Even if I were willing to do that (which I am not), my local disk does not have the capacity to do that.

How can I detect duplicates among my Dropbox files? In my case, I do not need to compare file contents. I can assume that files are duplicate if the filename and size is identical (not the date). **How can I detect such duplicates entirely in my Dropbox online files without downloading anything locally?**

Based on searching, the only third-party solution I have found that seems to offer this functionality is [Sorcim's Cloud Duplicate Finder](https://www.cloudduplicatefinder.com). I am hesitant to give access to my Dropbox to an unknown company and its solution is rather expensive (minimum 40 USD for three-month access). However, if there is no more affordable solution and someone can help me verify its trustworthiness, I would definitely consider an option like this.

Comment: From "[Using the Dropbox website](https://help.dropbox.com/installs/homepage#:~:text=Click%20Organize%20to%20use%20Multi%2Dfile%20organize%2C%20Set%20naming%20conventions%2C%20Find%20Duplicates%2C%20or%20Add%20automations "help.dropbox.com/installs/homepage")",  "Click **Organize** to use Multi-file organize, Set naming conventions, [Find Duplicates](https://help.dropbox.com/installs/homepage#:~:text=Click%20Organize%20to%20use%20Multi%2Dfile%20organize%2C%20Set%20naming%20conventions%2C%20Find%20Duplicates%2C%20or%20Add%20automations) or Add automations"

Comment: @BlindSpots I see the text you mentioned, but I cannot find any "Find Duplicates" option in my Dropbox and there are no details on the page you linked. Do you have more details about this?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't solved this already, you might want to take a look at the [Detect duplicates on Dropbox](https://www.simworkflow.com/pages/2epJLboCrAHE8clmadigpk) workflow from [SimWorkflow](https://www.simworkflow.com/).

It uses the Dropbox API to retrieve file metadata and compares hashes for all files to generate a summary of duplicate files. It does not access the file contents directly.

Disclosure: I am the founder of SimWorkflow, but I am also using it to help me find duplicates on Dropbox. :)

Comment: Welcome to [Web Apps SE](/tour)! If you want to recommend your own product or website, there are some [guidelines in place](/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Please [edit] your post to explicitly state your affiliation. Clarify what you mean by "*I run SimWorkflow*". (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)

Comment: It would be helpful to explain if it addresses the second part removal.

Comment: Another HTTP Task can be added in to remove the duplicates, it's intentionally not to have the removal part.

However, it addresses the key question: "How can I detect such duplicates entirely in my Dropbox online files without downloading anything locally?"